# Create a DataFrame from a XML File

Tags: python, dataframe, xml-parsing

im new to XML and i want to know how to create a dataframe in python from this XML file.

```
<EXTENDEDPROPERTIES>
<DEBTCONFIGURATION>
    <row Key="guid" Value="2018438038"/>
    <row Key="status" Value="0"/>
    <row Key="forma_pago" Value="DEBITO A CUENTA"/>
    <row Key="monto" Value="23699.1"/>
    <row Key="monto_abono" Value="360.55"/>
    <row Key="entidad" Value="BANCO CAPRICHOSO S.A."/>
    <row Key="tipo" Value="PREST. AUTO"/>
    <row Key="balance" Value="19617.5"/>
    <row Key="KIND_ID" Value="PRINCIPAL"/>
    <row Key="TYPE_ID" Value="CEDULA_IDENTIDAD"/>
    <row Key="CUSTOMER_ID" Value="777-555-888"/>
    <row Key="MEMBER_TYPE" Value="DEUDOR"/>
</DEBTCONFIGURATION>
```

I have the following code, it creates the DataFrame but when i tried to append the value of the row, i dont know why it keeps coming "None".

I dont know if i have to change de calling argument i.e Attrib.get.

Also i tried changing the attrib.get to find("value").text but it give me the error that it dosnt have the a text attribute.

```
import pandas as pd 
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xtree = ET.parse("davi_apc.xml")
xroot = xtree.getroot()
 
df_cols = ["guid", "status", "forma_pago", "monto", "monto_abono", "entidad", "tipo", "balance","KIND_ID", "TYPE_ID", "CUSTOMER_ID", "MEMBER_TYPE"]

rows = []

for node in xroot: 
    s_guid = node.attrib.get("guid")
    s_status = node.attrib.get("status")
    s_formapago = node.attrib.get("forma_pago")
    s_monto = node.attrib.get("monto")
    s_monto_abono = node.attrib.get("monto_abono")
    s_entidad = node.attrib.get("entidad")
    s_tipo = node.attrib.get("tipo")
    s_balance = node.attrib.get("balance")
    s_kind_id = node.attrib.get("KIND_ID")
    s_type_id = node.attrib.get("TYPE_ID")
    s_customer_id = node.attrib.get("CUSTOMER_ID")
    s_mebder_type = node.attrib.get("MEMBER_TYPE")
        

rows.append({
    "guid" : s_guid, 
    "status" : s_status, 
    "forma_pago" : s_formapago, 
    "monto" : s_monto, 
    "monto_abono" : s_monto_abono, 
    "entidad" : s_entidad, 
    "tipo" : s_tipo, 
    "balance" : s_balance,
    "KIND_ID" : s_kind_id,
    "TYPE_ID" : s_type_id, 
    "CUSTOMER_ID" : s_customer_id,
    "MEMBER_TYPE" : s_mebder_type
})


out_df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns = df_cols)
```

this is the printout of print(rows)
[{'guid': None, 'status': None, 'forma_pago': None, 'monto': None, 'monto_abono': None, 'entidad': None, 'tipo': None, 'balance': None, 'KIND_ID': None, 'TYPE_ID': None, 'CUSTOMER_ID': None, 'MEMBER_TYPE': None}]

and this is the printout of the dataframe
guid status forma_pago monto monto_abono entidad  tipo balance KIND_ID  
0  None   None       None  None        None    None  None    None    None

TYPE_ID CUSTOMER_ID MEMBER_TYPE
0    None        None        None

Comment: Can you show a little more of your code? Is that the full xml file? How are you importing the xml?

Comment: yes, thats the full xml file. im importing with                       xtree = ET.parse("davi_apc.xml")
xroot = xtree.getroot()

Comment: If you want to create a dataframe object, you should import pandas and get the dataframe doc here : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html; What appends when you print(rows) ? and could you show exact error message ?

Comment: You should write a working small example : see [MRE] so we can reproduce and help.

Comment: @Malo is correct -- we really need to see an example of what you're doing.... include the imports (and especially aliases! You're probably using `import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET`, but we can't know without a full example. Also, try to include the versions you're using -- at least the python version. From the syntax you're using it's obviously 3.x, but occasionally there can be behavior discrepancies if you're using 3.7.2 vs. 3.9.1 (versions pulled out of my ass - but you get the point)

Comment: I added the whole script and the results so you guys can check it out. thanks

Comment: Please accept edits in the edit queue so others can improve your question

Comment: is enabled, i think...

Comment: At the bottom of your post, on the left side, where you see the `Edit` link, it should have a number next to it (e.g. `Edit (5)`). This means you have suggested edits. Click it to review edits made to your post, and either accept or reject them.

Comment: Perfect thanks. then I have 0 because it has no number

Comment: Odd. It says your queue is full when I try to edit it. My 9 month old is waking up so I can't write a proper answer atm, but for one, your xml file is formatted improperly. You need to close the EXTENDEDPROPERTIES tag by adding `</EXTENDEDPROPERTIES>` at the end -- also, indent each level. Indent the whole <DEBTCONFIGURATION> block. It is also much easier to work with xml if you formatted it like `<guid>2018438038</guid>` instead of `<row Key="guid" Value="2078438038"/>` -- more options are available to you with fewer lines of code. I'll check back in a bit and help out if no one else has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working solution:

1/ remove top line from xml file, I am unsure if the first tag is xml compliant ?

```
<DEBTCONFIGURATION>
    <row Key="guid" Value="2018438038"/>
    <row Key="status" Value="0"/>
    <row Key="forma_pago" Value="DEBITO A CUENTA"/>
    <row Key="monto" Value="23699.1"/>
    <row Key="monto_abono" Value="360.55"/>
    <row Key="entidad" Value="BANCO CAPRICHOSO S.A."/>
    <row Key="tipo" Value="PREST. AUTO"/>
    <row Key="balance" Value="19617.5"/>
    <row Key="KIND_ID" Value="PRINCIPAL"/>
    <row Key="TYPE_ID" Value="CEDULA_IDENTIDAD"/>
    <row Key="CUSTOMER_ID" Value="777-555-888"/>
    <row Key="MEMBER_TYPE" Value="DEUDOR"/>
</DEBTCONFIGURATION>
```

2/ code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xtree = ET.parse("davi_apc.xml")
xroot = xtree.getroot()
 
rows = [{}]

for node in xroot:
    print(node.attrib)
    rows[0].update({node.attrib['Key']:node.attrib['Value']})
    
out_df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

3/ output for out_df:

```
out_df.head(10)
         guid status  ...  CUSTOMER_ID MEMBER_TYPE
0  2018438038      0  ...  777-555-888      DEUDOR
```